# Adjoint of coboundary map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex, hodge-theory

I am confused with the adjoint of the coboundary map as described in this article (https://magnus.ece.gatech.edu/Papers/MuhammadEgerstedtMTNS06.pdf, page 4).

The adjoint of the coboundary map is defined as $$\delta_k^*=\partial_{k+1}.$$ This is all well and good.

What confuses me is the domain and codomain of $\Delta_k:C^k(X,\mathbb{R})\to C^k(X,\mathbb{R})$, where $$\Delta_k=\delta_{k-1}\delta^*_{k-1}+\delta_k^*\delta_k.$$

The domain and codomain of the boundary/coboundary maps are:

$$\partial_k:C_k(X)\to C_{k-1}(X)$$ and $$\delta_i:C^i(X;\mathbb{R})\to C^{i+1}(X;\mathbb{R}).$$

This doesn't seem to be compatible with the domain and codomain of $\Delta_k$, does it?

My guess is that $\delta_k^*=\partial_{k+1}$ refers to the formula, not the domain/codomain. So for instance $[v_0,v_1]^*$ is the cochain that is 1 on the edge $[v_0,v_1]$ and 0 otherwise, then $$\partial_0^*[v_0,v_1]^*=\partial_1[v_0,v_1]^*=v_1^*-v_0^*$$

Is that the correct interpretation?

Thanks for any enlightenment.

Comment: The author seems to have imposed an inner product structure on $C_\bullet(X; \Bbb R)$ (canonically chosen so that the basis of oriented $\bullet$-simplices on $X$ makes an orthogonal basis). That provides a canonical isomorphism between $C_\bullet(X; \Bbb R)$ and the dual space $C^\bullet(X; \Bbb R)$. Given that, the domain issue vanishes; $\Delta_k$ is a linear transformation of $\Bbb R^n$ where $n$ is the number of $k$-simplices in $X$ (that's why the author speaks about it as a matrix below the definition, eg). Exciting article, by the way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is the canonical isomorphism something like $\sigma\to\sigma^*$, where $\sigma^*$ is the cochain with value 1 on the simplex $\sigma$ and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Well, it's given by $\sigma \mapsto \sigma^*$ such that $\sigma^*(s) = \langle \sigma, s \rangle$, where $\langle -, -\rangle$ is the chosen inner product.